# Making Callouts not appear in certain area of MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, mkmapview

With my previous question: [Detect Callout overlap other UIViews in MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41824421/detect-callout-overlap-other-uiviews-in-mkmapview), I thought - can I make **callouts** of an `MKMapView` **NOT** appear at certain part of the view and make it disappear when the user scrolls so that it will not go under any overlays that I create?

**EDIT**

I got the part about making it disappear by:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    for annotation in mapView.selectedAnnotations {
        mapView.deselectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
    }
}
```

I still have not figure out how to prevent the callout from appearing right under overlaying `UIViews`

Comment: Can I see your gif image so that I can understand your requirement better.

Comment: Basically I want to prevent the callout appearing at certain screen position due to certain UIViews I have overlaying the map. But I cannot find the screen position of the callouts.

Comment: I actually have no idea what visual will help describe the scenario...

Comment: I think it's hard to get the screen position of callout. By default they appear on top of annotations I believe. Do you think making a transparent background to the call outs would help you.. Try contact these people if possible, I hope this helps [Cocoa Controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/).